# Input : How to retrieve my value into my field "city"

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript, I am stuck on a simple problem. I know the question exists but I don't understand my problem.

I have an `input` named **city** and a `button`. When I enter a value, I don't retrieve the value, after confirming via my `button` **confirm**.

My HTML

```
<label>City:<input type="text" id="city" /></label></br>
<button id="btn">Confirm</button>
```

JavaScript (my problem)

```
let nameCity = document.getElementById('city');
let buttonConfirm = document.getElementById('btn');

buttonConfirm.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(){
    alert('You live in ' + nameCity);
}
```

```js
let nameCity = document.getElementById('city');
let buttonConfirm = document.getElementById('btn');

buttonConfirm.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(){
     alert('You live in ' + nameCity);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="Thing.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <label>City:<input type="text" id="city" /></label></br>
  <button id="btn">Confirm</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `document.getElementById('city')` you are getting the whole element (your input) with all the attributes and properties but it seems you only want to display the value.

So use `nameCity.value` in your function and you should get what you want.

```js
let nameCity = document.getElementById('city');
let buttonConfirm = document.getElementById('btn');

buttonConfirm.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(){
     alert('You live in ' + nameCity.value);
}
```

```html
<label>City:<input type="text" id="city" /></label></br>
<button id="btn">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understood.